# altbeacon with service class- android

Tags: java, android, service, altbeacon, beacon

I am scanning my beacons with **albeacon** library in a class that extends **Service** class

```
public class BeaconActivity extends Service implements BeaconConsumer{}
```

My question are:

1- Where to start/stop this **Service**? If I want the app scans all the time

```
 startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BeaconActivity.class));
 stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BeaconActivity.class));
```

2- Can I start/stop this Service using some **buttons**?

e.g. when start button pressed the app start scanning...

This is my class:

```
public class BeaconActivity extends Service implements BeaconConsumer {

BeaconManager beaconManager;
private static final String UUID1 = "B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D";
private static final String Major1 = "14152";
public static boolean isInBeaconRegion =false;
int value, id,distance;
String beaconMinor;


public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();


    beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().clear();
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));

    // 5 seconds
    beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(8000l);
    beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(8000l);

    beaconManager.bind(this);   }

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // -- continue running until it is stopped --
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return START_STICKY; }

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }

@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {

    beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> collection, Region region) {
            for (int i = 0; i < collection.size(); i++) {

                final Beacon beacon = collection.iterator().next();

                // -- Get Beacon UUID --
                String UUID2 = beacon.getId1().toString().toUpperCase();
                // -- Get Beacon Minor --
                String Major2 = beacon.getId2().toString();

                if (UUID2.equals(UUID1) && Major2.equals(Major1)) {

                    // -- Get Beacon Minor --
                    beaconMinor = beacon.getId3().toString();
                  //Check the minor

                } } }

    });

    try {
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D", null, null, null));
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

A few tips:

1. The [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) already has its own service that does scanning and easily lets you scan all the time.  You can see how to set this up [here.](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/background_launching.html)  As a result, making your own scanning service is not absolutely necessary.
2. If you do want to create your own Service, you can start and stop it inside a button like this:

   ```
   private boolean mServiceStarted = false;
   public View.OnClickListener startButtonTapped = new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           if (!mServiceStarted) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BeaconActivity.class);
               startService(intent);
               mServiceStarted = true;
           }
       }
   };
   public View.OnClickListener stopButtonTapped = new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           if (mServiceStarted) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BeaconActivity.class);
               stopService(intent);
               mServiceStarted = false;
           }
       }
   };
   ```
3. You may want to rename the class "BeaconActivity" to something like "BeaconScanningService", since it is a standard convention to name Android service classes this way.

Comment: got it. But what if the user press (Start scanning) and there are no beacons around him? where can I put this warning Toast? -my class is attached